# How can I return an array from a HTML selectbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing select options and optgroups in a JavaScipt array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992582/storing-select-options-and-optgroups-in-a-javascipt-array)

Here's my HTML:

```
<select name="select">
   <option value='xxx'> xXx </option>    
   <optgroup label="Letters">
       <option value='a'> A </option>
       <option value='b'> B </option>
       <option value='c'> C </option>
       <option value='d'> D </option>
   </optgroup>
   <option value='zzz'> zZz </option>
</select>
```

I'm now trying to get array from select box's children to be like this:

```
[{"xxx":"xXx"},{"letters":{"a":"A","b":"B","c":"C","d":"D"}},{"zzz":"zZz"}]
```

Dependent on select box options and option group.

Comment: Nearly exact same question I answered yesterday... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992582/storing-select-options-and-optgroups-in-a-javascipt-array/12992604#12992604

Comment: Thank you @Michael Berkowski, I think i will use the answer for your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the code that you've asked for.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var mtest = "[";
var i = 0;
var j = 0;

$("select").children().each(function() { 
 if (i==0) i+=1; else  mtest += ','; 
 j = 0;
if ($(this).children().length ==0) { 
     mtest += '{"' + $(this).attr('value') + '":"' +  $.trim($(this).html()) + '"}';
} else {
    mtest += '{"' + $(this).attr('label') + '":{';
    $(this).children().each(function() { 
        if (j==0) j+=1; else  mtest += ','; 
        mtest += '"' + $(this).attr('value') + '":"' + $.trim($(this).html()) + '"';

    });
  mtest += '}';
}

;})
mtest += ']';
document.write(mtest);

});​
```

Here http://jsfiddle.net/salih0vicX/WkaNv/ you can test it; I've added some extra HTML for testing purpose...

Please let me know if you have any questions or concern.

Comment: Thank you @salih0vicX , it work fine with me , and there is other question same to my " duplicate " thanks again